# Why pytorch can't run model on CUDA?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am relatively new to the field. I am trying a simple tutorial to run a pytorch model (simple linear regression) on CUDA. The code seems to load the data to GPU memory, but the model execution seems to be done on CPU instead. I made sure to send the model to GPU, but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
#Function to return a dataloader
#x_train and y_train are np arrays of 800 points following y=wx+b+gaussian noise.
def create_data():
    x_train_tensor = torch.as_tensor(x_train, dtype=torch.float)
    y_train_tensor = torch.as_tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float)
    train_data = TensorDataset(x_train_tensor,y_train_tensor)
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
    return train_loader

class MLR(nn.Module):
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1,1)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

def mdl_def(device):
    lr=0.1
    model1 = MLR() #create model object
    model1.to(device) #send model to device
    optimizer= optim.SGD(model1.parameters(), lr=lr) #define how to update parameters
    loss_fn= nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean') #define loss function
    train_step = make_train_step(model1, loss_fn, optimizer)
    return train_step, model1

def mini_batch(step, device):
    mini_batch_losses=[]
    train_loader = create_data()
    for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        x_batch = x_batch.to(device)
        y_batch = y_batch.to(device)
        mini_batch_loss = step(x_batch,y_batch)
        mini_batch_losses.append(mini_batch_loss)
    loss = np.mean(mini_batch_losses)
    return loss

def make_train_step(model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    def perform_train_step(x,y):
        model.train() #put model in train mode
        yhat = model(x) #forward prediction
        loss = loss_fn(yhat, y) #calculate loss
        loss.backward() #backward computation for gradients
        optimizer.step() #update model parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad() #Reset gradients
        return loss.tolist()#model.state_dict()
    return perform_train_step

def train(device):
    n_epochs = 1000
    losses=[]
    train_step, model1 = mdl_def(device)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        loss = mini_batch(train_step, device)
        losses.append(loss)
    return losses, model1.state_dict()
```

Running the above with a Jupyter cell for CPU:

```
%%time
ls, sd = train('cpu')
print(sd)
```

I get the following output:

```
OrderedDict([('linear.weight', tensor([[1.9797]])), ('linear.bias', tensor([1.0099]))])
Wall time: 12.7 s
```

Running the above with a Jupyter cell for GPU:

```
%%time
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
ls, sd = train(device)
print(device)
print(sd)
```

I get the following output:

```
cuda
OrderedDict([('linear.weight', tensor([[1.9797]], device='cuda:0')), ('linear.bias', tensor([1.0099], device='cuda:0'))])
Wall time: 29.4 s
```

In addition, when I monitor the execution in Task Manager, in both cases I get a surge in CPU utilization. Although in the CUDA case I can see an increase in memory usage, but GPU utilization is 0~1% and when I add the compute_0 or compute_1 graphs in Task Manager, they are both solid 0s.

I installed previously both CUDA toolkit and cudnn, but just an installation. Didn't tamper with them much.

My setup is a laptop with Windows10, x64, NVIDIA GTX 1650Ti, Anaconda 3 (Conda 4.10.3), Python 3.8.8.

Comment: just pointing out that formatting codes uses ``` not `'''`. Also adding the python tag is recommended

Comment: Can you monitor your GPU memory usage with `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: @I_love_vegetables: Thanks for pointing that out. It's my first post, surely will take care of that.

Comment: @Ivan: Yes i used command `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu,utilization.memory,memory.total,memory.free,memory.used --format=csv -l 1 -f ./GPU_Stats.csv` to log to csv and I got utilization ranging between 4 to 13%, averaging at 9%. Also utilization memory % goes up to 14% during first 7 seconds, and then drops to 1%, although the same records show memory.used(MiB) up to 565 MiB during those first 7 seconds, and then surged to 1306 MiB. I think this somehow means GPU is really processing my model above, although I couldn't understand how the GPU takes more time than my CPU? Any Ideas?

Comment: This could be the case when the model is not heavy. You could try adding `pin_memory=True` in your `DataLoader`